# compile error in VeridisBiometricSDK_5.0_Linux sample: MatchingExample

Tags: c++, linux, centos

I try to use VeridisBiometricSDK_5.0_Linux which is free Biometric library which  has samples   I tired to compile MatchingExample by doing exactly what the Readme file said :
 make MatchingExample.cpp
but I have this error result:

```
root@localhost MatchingExample]# make MatchingExample
g++ -Wall -g  MatchingExample.cpp -o ../../../bin/MatchingExample -I../../../include/ -L../../../lib/   -lVrBio -lpthread -ludev -lusb -lusb-1.0 -ldl
MatchingExample.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
MatchingExample.cpp:47: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
MatchingExample.cpp:55: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libtiff.so.4, needed by ../../../lib//libVrBio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFDefaultStripSize'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `__fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `_TIFFmalloc'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFSetErrorHandler'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `_TIFFfree'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFClientOpen'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFSetWarningHandler'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MatchingExample] Error 1
==================================================
this is the Makefile codes:
# ------------------ Compilation options ------------------------
# Loads libraries. 
LIBS = -lVrBio -lpthread -ludev -lusb -lusb-1.0 -ldl

# Flags for the C compiler:
#   -Wall for strict gcc warnings (requires prototypes for all functions).
#   -g to produce debug data for gdb
#   -O for optimization
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

CC = g++
# --------------------- Directory Paths ----------------------------

INC_DIRS = -I../../../include/

LIB_DIRS = -L../../../lib/

BIN_DIR = ../../../bin/

# --------------------- Code modules ----------------------------

# Object files
#OBJ =

# Definitions
#DEFS = 
# ------------------------ Rules --------------------------------

$@.cpp: $@.cpp 
    ${CC} $(CFLAGS) $@.cpp -o $(BIN_DIR)$@ $(INC_DIRS) $(LIB_DIRS)   $(LIBS)
==========================
aslo this is the ReadMe file content
In the AsyncCaptureExample folder there is a Makefile. This Makefile can be used for all the
other cpp examples.
```

To compile use: make

For example: make AsyncCaptureExample

## The output will be generated in the bin folder.

also this is the VeridisBiometricSDK_5.0 ReadMe file:
1 - install necessary packages:
 *libudev
 *libusb
 *libusb-1.0
 *fxload
2 - In the misc folder there are files necessary for the program access the USB with the extension .rules. Copy them
    to /etc/udev/rules.d folder or equivalent

3 - mkdir /usr/share/usb and copy the .hex files of the misc folder there
4 - Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH as the path to the .so files

5 - copy the file UFLicense.dat, which is in the misc folder,  to the folder of your application
    if you use suprema readers.

would you please help me?

**UPDATE**

I am so close to solve my problem:
First, I found solution for installing libtiff.so.4 for Ubuntu on this the following link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/457011/why-is-libtiff-so-4-not-recognized
Second, I convert the same Ubuntu library package into centos rpm using alien tool as the following:
alien -r  -g  libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Third, I Installed libtiff4-3.9.7-3.x86_64.rpm (which is result from alien converting) on my Centos 6.7 it installed successfully but when try make my samples I supersized that libtiff.so.4 requires 2 library which are

```
[root@localhost]# readelf  -d  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libjbig.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libjpeg.so.8]
```

I installed libjpeg.so.8 from source code library from jpegsrc.v8.tar.gz and it worked well
    But I couldn’t find any suitable package to fix missing libbig.so.0 library 
    So would you help me to fix this missing library…
    By way the when I fixed my problem, I will explain the all solution so it will be useful for any one

Comment: Where did the `../../../lib//libVrBio.so` file come from? It appears to be failing to link against the `tiff` library.

Comment: libVrBio file come from library directory ... also my centos machine doesn't have any libtiff.so.4 but it has libtiff.so   >>>>http://imgur.com/J1ZGkFc

Comment: From *what* library directory? Where did it come from? Did you build it as part of this installation attempt? What is that a screenshot of?

Comment: I did that in the readme library before I tried to copmpile the example as I explained before in my question

Comment: If you built it on your machine then it should be linked against a library you have available.

Comment: I knew that but it didn't linked >>>>>>http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=71266488592012061640&t=7126648859201206164010565

Comment: Is that the tarball you downloaded originally? Or is that an archive of your built directory?

Comment: what do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: That tar.gz file you just linked to. What is it? Is that the original source archive you downloaded from the `VeridisBiometricSDK` site? Is it an archive of your local source directory after you tried to build things?

Comment: yes, php.ini on
VeridisBiometricSDK_5.0_Linux.tar.gz
this is orginal library achive file, I extracted it and then I work on resulting folder

Comment: That archive has prebuilt libraries in it. Those libraries clearly aren't built for your system (and likely shouldn't be in that archive). You either need a more appropriate archive or you need to rebuild those libraries it looks like.

Comment: would you please help me in how I can do it??

Comment: I don't know. If the sources for it are in that archive you should be able to compile it easily enough (I hope). But with a project that produces an archive like this I wouldn't bet on it all working well. You would probably be better off finding out if they have an official support forum/mailing list/etc. and asking there. (Or looking for more in depth documentation.)

Comment: this library doesn't have any source code, this archive file is only available from http://veridisbiometrics.com/ web site have urgent out office issues so will you wait me to do what you want?

Comment: Yeah. I figured as much. Then those built libraries don't work on your system and you have to find out what sort of system they *are* built for and whether there are binaries for your system or not. There's nothing I can do for you at this point. You most likely can't get this to work on your current system with those libraries. You need to deal with the people who made the library/software.

Comment: I tried this solution:
first create symbolic link ln -s /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.3.9.4 /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.4  
then I did the command [root@localhost MatchingExample]# make MatchingExample
it had an error result as:

Comment: MatchingExample.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
MatchingExample.cpp:47: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
MatchingExample.cpp:55: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `__fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15'
../../../lib//libVrBio.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [MatchingExample] Error 1

Comment: Yeah, "random" symlinks in system directories like that are **never** the right solution. The resulting error is because it is the wrong library version. That "solution" just isn't going to work. You really just need to go to the vendor for this.

Comment: I enter vendor website:
http://veridisbiometrics.com ,but I don't find any contact information ...

Comment: If you can't find any vendor contact information and the documentation doesn't tell you what the target platform for the distribution is and you can't make it work then, perhaps, this isn't the right vendor to be using software from... Just a thought.

Comment: I am so close to solve my problem:
First, I found solution for installing libtiff.so.4 for Ubuntu on this the following link:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/457011/why-is-libtiff-so-4-not-recognized

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457011/why-is-libtiff-so-4-not-recognized
Second, I convert the same Ubuntu library package into centos rpm using alien tool as the following:

Comment: alien -r  -g  libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Third, I Installed libtiff4-3.9.7-3.x86_64.rpm (which is result from alien converting) on my Centos 6.7 it installed successfully but when try make my samples I supersized that libtiff.so.4 requires 2 library which are

Comment: [root@localhost]# readelf  -d  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.4
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libjbig.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libjpeg.so.8]

Comment: You are close to **nothing** at this point but a *seriously* confused and broken system. You are attacking this problem in **entirely** the wrong way.

Comment: My Library work well under Ubuntu!

Comment: Yes, because clearly that's the system it was designed for (at least at whatever version of Ubuntu they built it). The problem is it **isn't** set up for just about anything else and since you can't build it you can't **make** it ready for anything else. So, once again, this is a vendor problem. Your vendor isn't giving you what you want in a way that you can use it. Instead of *torturing* your CentOS system to try to make it sort-of fit you should either use the "right" version of Ubuntu or go ask the vendor to give you something that works better on CentOS.

Comment: The vendor is not supported this library right now ... what should I do to run it at CentOS as I did it on Ubuntu???

Comment: You keep bastardizing your system to get just the right pieces cobbled together to satisfy the requirements of this (unsupported) library and end up with a mess of a system that you probably can't maintain and can't get support for. Or you find a different (and supported) library to use instead.

Comment: may you help me in find alternative library, because I couldn't find better than this library??

Comment: I have no idea what that library does. I have no idea what other libraries exist in this space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem
if you read my problem you would know that my problem is missing libtiff.so.4

I fixed it,
my solutions steps as follows
first
if you dipslay current libtiff.so by using this command

```
[yaserco@localhost Desktop]$ locate libtiff.so
/usr/lib64/libtiff.so.3
```

so I made symble link to libtiff.so.3

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.3 /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.4
```

after I tested my sample it diplayed this 2 error messages
tried this solution: first create symbolic link ln -s /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.3.9.4 /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.4 then I did the command [root@localhost MatchingExample]# make MatchingExample it had an error result as:

```
MatchingExample.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
MatchingExample.cpp:47: warning: deprecated conversion from 
string constant to ‘char*’ MatchingExample.cpp:55: warning: deprecated

conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ ../../../lib//libVrBio.so: 

undefined reference to __fdelt_chk@GLIBC_2.15' ../../../lib//libVrBio.so: 
undefined reference to memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
```

second
I solved this error by installing

A-
glibc for (GLIBC_2.14) as the follows:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.16.0.tar.gz
tar -xvzf glibc-2.16.0.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.16.0
mkdir glibc-build
cd glibc-build
../configure --prefix='/usr'
```

B-

We have to fix a little typo, so run:

```
nano +171 ../scripts/test-installation.pl

and replace if (/$ld_so_name/) { with if (/\Q$ld_so_name\E/) {
:

make
sudo make install
```

see more form this link
https://github.com/FezVrasta/ark-server-tools/wiki/Install-of-required-versions-of-glibc-and-gcc-on-RHEL-CentOS
then when I compile my sample it worked well